# VSTS Unit test error message

Tags: azure-pipelines

I woke up this morning to receive the following error message from my NUnit tests in VSTS:

```
`##[section]Starting: Test Assemblies **\*.Unit.Tests.dll;-:**\obj\**
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Test
Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
Version      : 2.0.30
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
==============================================================================
!**\obj\**
[command]powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file d:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.30\vs15Helper.ps1
Does not exist.
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Nil />
</Objs>
##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
##[section]Finishing: Test Assemblies **\*.Unit.Tests.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

Just started happening, can anyone tell me why? I am using the Visual Studio Version 2 build step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the corresponding version of visual studio that the build agent server has.

[image]

Comment: How would I know which version the build agent server has?

Comment: @johnstaveley You can check capabilities of related agent. 1. Go to https://[account].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_admin/_AgentQueue; 2. Select a agent queue; 3. Select a agent; 4. Select Capabilities 5. Check the value of VisualStudio item. (...14.0 means VS 2015,...2017 mean VS 2017)

Comment: I had 14, even though I am developing in VS2017, any chance the error message can be improved?

Comment: @johnstaveley You could use Hosted VS2017 agent directly or setup a on premise build agent on the machine has VS 2017 installed.

Comment: I never had this issue before, been using this agent for months and suddenly it refuses to work and gives me an obscure error message :( Thanks for your help